# Filtering an old list to a new list C#

Tags: c#, list

I want to compare 2 lists.

1 list has some `GlueLines`these are objects with 2 properties: `StartPosition`, `EndPosition` (both `PointF`)

List 2 is empty and needs to be filled with new lines.

I only want to add a new `GlueLine` when there is no other object in the DrawLines list with that specific StartPosition.Y value.

Below you can find the code:

```
List<GlueLine> SortedList;
List<GlueLine> DrawLines = new List<GlueLine>();

SortedList = a_listGlueLines.OrderBy(o => Math.Round(o.StartPosition.X, 2)).ToList();

for(int i =0; i <SortedList.Count; i++)
{
    if(DrawLines.Count < 0)
    {
         for(int j = 0; j < DrawLines.Count; j++)
         {
            if(SortedList[i].StartPosition.Y != DrawLines[...].StartPosition.Y) // ... needs to be ALL of the objects in that list
            {
              DrawLines.Add(SortedList[i]);
            }
         }
    }
    else
    {
          DrawLines.Add(SortedList[i]);
    }
}
```

Or is there some other way to compare 1 object of 1 list to all the objects in the other list?

Comment: how does `.Any`work?

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) is your friend.

Comment: Besides: There's a type in the line 

if(DrawLines.Count < 0)

I think you want

if(DrawLines.Count > 0)

Comment: @Bart, at the moment you are testing if DrawLines has **less than zero** lines. That can never happen. I can have zero or more than zero lines, but never less than zero.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for the tip, never used this before :) but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy/), which has a `DistinctBy` method.

```
IEnumerable<GlueLines> distinctLinesByY = lines.DistinctBy(line => line.Y);
```

If you don't want to depend on the library, just implement the one method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                                 Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        return source.Where(element => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it efficiently, I would use a `Dictionary<Single,GlueLine>` with the key being the Y coordinate. ie change

```
List<GlueLine> DrawLines = new List<GlueLine>();
```

to

```
Dictionary<Single,GlueLine> DrawLines = new Dictionary<Single,GlueLine>();
```

You can replace the inside of your loop with

```
if (!DrawLines.ContainsKey(SortedList[i].StartPosition.Y))
    DrawLines.Add(SortedList[i].StartPosition.Y, SortedList[i])
```

If speed isn't an issue then you can use a linq query to select the distinct Y coordinates into a list, then select from each of those, the First matching GlueLine.  This isn't very efficient, but you might feel it is easier to code/read.

Comment: 'List<GlueLine>' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey' and no extension method 'ContainsKey' accepting a first argument of type 'List<GlueLine>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Change 
    List<GlueLine> DrawLines = new List<GlueLine>();
to 
    Dictionary<Single,GlueLine> DrawLines = new Dictionary<Single,GlueLine>();

Answer (score 0):

i see you want to do it from scratch... here is a way to do it

```
List<GlueLine> SortedList;
List<GlueLine> DrawLines = new List<GlueLine>();
SortedList = a_listGlueLines.OrderBy(o => Math.Round(o.StartPosition.X,2)).ToList();

foreach(GlueLine current in SortedList){
    Boolean found = false;
    foreach(GlueLine anyLine in DrawLines){
        if(current.StartPosition.Y == anyLine.StartPosition.Y){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        DrawLines.Add(current);
    }
}
```

if you want a more elegant way you can go with [Kvam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392287/kvam) solution